# How to call built-in or third party alexa skills from my skill

Tags: alexa-voice-service, alexa-skills-kit

I'd like to be able to run built-in or third-party skills from my Alexa skill. For example, I'd like to be able to say

"Alexa, start naptime"

and have Alexa turn off all lights, start a specific Tune-In station, and set a 30-minute alarm. But I haven't been able to find a way in the Alexa Skills Kit to do this. Is this possible?

(Note: I'm specifically looking for solutions that I can implement in my own skill, as opposed to IFTTT recipes.)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen anything in the SDK that could be used to do this, so I believe that it is not possible at this time.

It is an interesting question though.  Sort of like 'intents' for Alexa.

Answer (score 0):

The Alexa voice service is a different thing than The Echo hardware device. Alexa can run on many different systems. Features that are specific to The Echo, such as spotify, alarms, timers, shopping lists, etc, are not accessible by Alexa, because they may not be on all devices.

The only way you can do something like this, which is fairly kludgey, is to have your skill playback a voice through a nearby PC that uses voice commands to get the Echo to do these things.